# If Elixir Regex is implemented with PCRE, why doesn't it support POSIX character classes?

Tags: regex, elixir

Elixir [`Regex`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Regex.html#content) is based on the [Erlang `:re` module](http://erlang.org/doc/man/re.html), which states in [its documentation](http://erlang.org/doc/man/re.html#posix-character-classes) that

> Perl supports the Posix notation for character classes. This uses
>   names enclosed by [: and :] within the enclosing square brackets. PCRE
>   also supports this notation.

POSIX character classes can be represented with either the `\p` operator à la [Unicode Properties](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) or with bracket class notation, as described [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html) and in the `:re` documentation.

Yet these are the results I have seen on my system using Elixir 1.9:

```
iex(1)> Regex.run(~r/\p{L}+/, "Götterfunken")
[<<71, 195>>]
```

I expected the above to match all characters in the search word.

```
iex(2)> Regex.run(~r/[[:alpha:]]+/, "Götterfunken")
[<<71, 195>>]
```

Again, I expected all characters to match, though I'm not sure if `:alpha:` is supposed to match non-latin characters.

```
iex(3)> Regex.run(~r/[[:punct:]]/, "Götterfunken")
[<<182>>]
```

Here, I expected no matches at all.

Is this a broken Regex implementation in Elixir, or am I failing to understand the correct usage?

Comment: Whats the idea in having inner delimiters `<< >>` surrounded by outer delimiters `[ ]` ?

Comment: Not sure why `\p{L}+` isn't working, but I can tell you that `[[:alpha:]]` won't work with non-Latin characters such as `ö`. Delete that character and it should start working.

Comment: I think either the regex is not initialized properly or the language needs upgrading. None of these answers are correct.

Comment: Whoever casts the final re-open vote, could you [push the target onto the close queue as a duplicate of this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57085347/5223757)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it turns out, the Elixir `Regex` module provides [an option to turn on support for Unicode](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Regex.html#module-modifiers):

> `unicode` (u) - enables Unicode specific patterns like \p and change
>   modifiers like \w, \W, \s and friends to also match on Unicode. It
>   expects valid Unicode strings to be given on match

That means the problem examples in the question can be solved like so:

```
iex(1)> Regex.run(~r/\p{L}+/u, "Götterfunken")
["Götterfunken"]

iex(2)> Regex.run(~r/[[:alpha:]]+/u, "Götterfunken")
["Götterfunken"]

iex(3)> Regex.run(~r/[[:punct:]]/u, "Götterfunken")
nil
```